# Почему страница, загруженная на сервер spaceWeb отличается от той, что развёрнута локально у меня на компьютере?

Tags: javascript, html, css, openstreetmap

Создал простой сайт с картой OpenStreetMap, загрузил на сервер не так давно, но заметил, что есть некоторые различия между ними -

1. на сайте, что с сервера нет логотипа страницы
2. Определение координат не работает, если заходить с компьютера - если же зайти с телефона, то всё в полном порядке.
3. Чекбокс гораздо меньшего размера, чем на сайте, который расположен на компе.
   Собственно, вот ссылка на сам сайт https://www.geokrasnodar.ru/
   В чём может быть дело?

   ```js
       // Создание слоя OSM на странице сайта
   var centerpos = [38.997190, 45.130683];
   var newpos = ol.proj.transform(centerpos, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913');
       // Установка визуализации OSM
   var view = new ol.View({
       projection: 'EPSG:900913',
       center: newpos,
       zoom: 2,
       maxZoom: 20,
       minZoom: 5,
       extent: [4262967.307515293, 5592508.683331995, 4429711.492867963, 5697114.645076073]
   });
       // Установка слоя ОСМ
   var map = new ol.Map({
       layers: [
           new ol.layer.Tile({
               source: new ol.source.OSM({
                   tileSize: 512,
                   maxResolution: 180 / 512,
                   wrapX: true,
                   view: view,
               }),
           })],
       keyboardEventTarget: document,
       target: 'map',
       view: view,
       minExtent: 10,
   });
       // Получить координаты щелчком мыши
   map.on('click', function (e) {
       let coord = e.coordinate
       console.log(coord);
   })
       //Создание иконки местонахождения пользователя
   var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation({
       trackingOptions: {
           enableHighAccuracy: true,
       },
       projection: view.getProjection(),
   });

   function el(id) {
       return document.getElementById(id);
   }

   el('whereAmI').addEventListener('change', function () {
       geolocation.setTracking(this.checked);
       console.log(geolocation.projection);
   });

   var accuracyFeature = new ol.Feature();

   geolocation.on('change:accuracyGeometry', function () {
       accuracyFeature.setGeometry(geolocation.getAccuracyGeometry());
       console.log(accuracyFeature);
   });

   var positionFeature = new ol.Feature();

   positionFeature.setStyle(
       new ol.style.Style({
           image: new ol.style.Circle({
               radius: 6,
               fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                   color: '#3399CC',
               }),
               stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                   color: '#fff',
                   width: 2,
               }),

           }),
       })
   );

   geolocation.on('change:position', function () {
       var coordinates = geolocation.getPosition();
       positionFeature.setGeometry(coordinates ? new ol.geom.Point(coordinates) : null);
   });

   new ol.layer.Vector({
       map: map,
       source: new ol.source.Vector({
           features: [accuracyFeature, positionFeature],
       }),
   });
   ```

   ```css
   body{
       padding:0;
       margin:0;
       overflow: hidden;
   }
   a{
       text-decoration:none;
       color: blue;
   }
   #map {
       height: 100vh;
       position: absolute;
       top: 0px;
       right: 0px;
       bottom: 0px;
       left: 0px;
       z-index: 2;
       margin-bottom: 50px;
   }
   #chbxTrack{
       z-index: 3;
       position: absolute;
       right: 220px;
       bottom:0px;
       font-size: 28px;
   }
   #track{
       width: 20px;
       height:20px;
       border-radius:50%;
   }
   #coord{
       position: absolute;
       left: 2.5em;
       bottom: .8em;
       z-index:101;
       background: none;
       color: black;
       font-size: 20px;
   }
   #I {
       z-index: 102;
       width: 66px;
       height: 66px;
       position: absolute;
       right: 1.4em;
       bottom: 2.5em;
   }
   #whereAmI {
       z-index: 0;
       width: 65px;
       height: 65px;
       background: url(../images/arrowMe.png);
       background-size: 65px 65px;
       border: 0px;
       border-radius: 50%;
       -moz-border-radius: 50%;
       -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
   }
   #whereAmI :active, .whereAmI:focus{
       outline: none;
   }
   #whereAmI ::-moz-focus-inner{
       border: 0;
   }
   #whereAmI{
       cursor:pointer;
   }
   /*.ol-attribution{
       background:black;
   }*/
   ```

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
       <title>ГеоКраснодар</title>
       <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/logo2.png" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ol.css" type="text/css">
       <script src="build/ol.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div class="container">
           <div id="map" ></div>
           <div id="I">
                   <input id="whereAmI" onclick="coordinateUser()" value="" type="checkbox" />       
           </div>  
           <script defer="defer" src="scripts/script.js"></script>
       </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Решил проблему перезапуском браузера
Не знаю, с чем это может быть связано, но думаю, что проблема крылась в кэше браузера